# What is the current Apple policy on purchases outside the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, development

We are developing an app for a customer that will sell content. There will also be an Android and web app and they don't really want to pay Apple 30% and would rather use their own site to sell.

For what I've read online, I understand that it's ok to sell content for the app elsewhere, but it is not allowed to link to the store from the app. Do I understand this correctly? There was also something about prices.

*Sorry, not sure if this question is more appropriate here or on StackOverflow. It's not really a coding question either.*

Comment: At the moment, this is off-topic here but please join the [discussion on meta](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/what-would-happen-if-we-expanded-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-itunes-connec). I have seen many questions on iTunes connect policy / procedure get closed on SO as well , so you'll need to ask there in chat if you want a moderator there to see this wording and let you know if it's likely to get closed there too. Most of the closed questions are just bad questions overall and I can't speak whether this would meet their criteria for being acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The rules of iTunes connect are only really available when you sign in to the service, and agree to the terms. I am not currently a developer so I don't know even if the details are protected by an NDA.

I don't have a link to a good press article covering the current state of affairs, but my understanding and gross oversimplification of the rules are:

- It's OK to enable extra content if the iOS app does nothing to link to, process, enroll or advertise the paid portion of the service or app.
- It's always OK to handle purchases through in-app purchase where Apple will take their cut of the sale in return for providing the accounting, customer service, billing, returns, server hardware, software and bandwidth for distribution of your app and the handling of the paid content sales. It's probably very not OK to sell in the app and not use Apple for the payment.
- Newsstand apps are different and I'll let someone who knows edit in how a subscription might be different than a one time sale, but I would be surprised if it was overall different than the normal in-app purchase policy.

If your work for your client is to advise them, you'll really want to just spend the $99 and join and have your team participate in the developer program NDA / restricted chats and or just read the terms of iTunes Connect. If not, it's their problem and make sure your contract with them is clear as to under whom all responsibility of knowing and adhering to the Terms and Conditions fall.