# Taking payments for in-app products outside of the app using download codes

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I have implemented in app payments for special content in my app.

I am curious if apple allows us taking payments through outside channels to unlock the same content with say a donwload code, as an alternate to the in-app payment method.

Is this against the terms?

Comment: Are you using Apple API for your current payment implementation?

Comment: Yes, I am using IAP. This could change if necessary.

Comment: Cool. It depends what precisely you are selling - in some cases yes, others now. The developer documentation covers this a [bit better than in 2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41825/5472) -  the main point is to discern if you’re selling physical goods, consumable IAP or [subscription.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/357226/5472). If you’re doin plainIAP, don’t go for epic effect...